# How to change web application settings via Powershell or SQL?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sql

Third-party tools like [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/) allow you to change settings on your web application. I need to toggle the [**LookupDropDownUseStandardControl**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.lookupdropdownusestandardcontrol.aspx) from TRUE to FALSE, but SharePoint Manager is not working for some reason. I posted this to the SPM site back in  December, then reported it as an issue  in January. I haven't gotten a response yet, and the business unit needs me to find an alternate way of fixing this issue. The setting was flagged TRUE after an update and broke all of our complex lookup dropdowns.

**Is there a way to apply this change via Powershell, or even in the database directly via SQL?**

I also have access to Visual Studio, although I'm only an amateur developer at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via PowerShell, this is simple.

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication https://webAppUrl
$wa.LookupDropDownUseStandardControl = $true | $false
$wa.Update()
```

Direct updates to SQL are wholly unsupported.

You'll use the SharePoint Management Shell on one of the SharePoint servers which is a member of the farm.

EDIT: Disregard the above. It can't be set!

```
public bool LookupDropDownUseStandardControl
{
    get => 
        true;
    set
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, fast too! Is there anything that would lock the setting to TRUE? Both this command and SPM seem to have no effect on the setting value.

Comment: Updated my post. It can't be set.